# Add custom event to Object3D

Tags: three.js

I am building a scenegraph out of Object3D nodes. Several of the nodes I would like to treat as Spin objects that are not active since the beginning but they become active when they receive a specific 'start' event, probably using a timer to fire it up. I need some assistance in setting this up. I have tried the following code

```
var spinner_obj = new THREE.Object3D();
spinner_obj.addEventListener('start', function(event) {alert("GOT THE EVENT");});
```

but this gives me an error "TypeError: spinner_obj.addEventListener is not a function"

In addition what would I have to do to fire this 'start' event? I am a javascript beginner. 
I have tried to follow https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js but I need some more pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var spinner_obj = new THREE.Object3D();
THREE.EventDispatcher.call( spinner_obj );
spinner_obj.addEventListener('start', function(event) {alert("GOT THE EVENT");});
spinner_obj.dispatchEvent({type:'start'});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to manually add "addEventListener", "removeEventListener" and "dispatchEvent" functions to Object3D.js file as long as it's not derived from EventDispatcher class.

Note: Also you should trigger "start" event inside somewhere in Object3D.js according to your  sample code.