# TrackBall not working in three.js

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js

I have tried and tested the 3d tube geometry. Please find code at following link.

I am trying to traverse path along the pipe using trackball but i am not able to figure out what's the problem. While debugging I receive error that addEventListener is not function of controls. Please help me for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/dR4qP/ `Code at above link`

Comment: you don't need to attach that event listener anyway as you are calling `animate()` every frame which does the rendering, if your way worked you would be calling `render()` multiple times per render loop which is wasteful and unnecessary. Just delete the line `controls.addEventListener('change',render);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trackball controls changed at some point and the following line was removed from the Trackball object:
    THREE.EventTarget.call( this );

Therefore the method addEventListener is not part of the Trackball object anymore.

The following question/answer will show you how to update your code :

[Add custom event to Object3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397596/add-custom-event-to-object3d)