# EventDispatcher (r58)

Tags: three.js

Something changed in regards to the EventDispatcer in r58 and I cannot add any more custom events to Objects. As per [Add custom event to Object3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397596/add-custom-event-to-object3d) I used to have:

```
var spinner_obj = new THREE.Object3D();
THREE.EventDispatcher.call( spinner_obj );
spinner_obj.addEventListener('start', function(event) {alert("GOT THE EVENT");});
spinner_obj.dispatchEvent({type:'start'});
```

but this stopped working in r58 with the error message:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's using a single instance of the functions instead of duplicating it in every object.

This is the best approach I've found so far:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js#L11-L14

I think I'll make Object3D extend EventDispatcher prototype though...

Comment: So you mean I dont have to call 'THREE.EventDispatcher.call' every time I want to add an event to an object? If not, how do I have to rewrite the above code.

Comment: Not if you're using r59dev+ :) https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/e347fc04de0e4ae18d2c426e2545afc7c2742bb3

Comment: I patched my version of the Object3D code as in the commit, removed all references to THREE.EventDispatcher.call from my objects but I am still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'" on one of my Object3D objects and "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'" on TrackballControls. I assume it is because I dont have the r59dev TrackballControls code (dont know how to get it) but still I have the problem of the EventListener on my Object3D.

Comment: That patch should work if you are using r58. EvendDispatcher changed from r57 to r58.

Comment: Weird... tried with r59dev? Oh, and yes. TrackballControls need to be from r58 too.

Comment: Oups ... big oups, mixed up the vevisions. In conclusion r58 with the patched Objet3D, works fine in regards to the EventDispatcher.