# is there an event fired when an object is done being added to a three.js scene, or the scene is otherwise "ready"?

Tags: events, three.js

i am trying to get an image of a three.js scene (via `renderer.domElement.toDataURL`).  it works fine, except i think i am running into a problem if i call it *immediately after some major changes* to the scene (e.g. `scene.add(mesh)` or a resize of the window), the image it gets is blank/empty (all transparent).  if i wait a second and manually call it, the image will appear.

is there an event that fires in three.js when the scene (or renderer, i guess?) is ready to be accessed as such?  i have tried adding event listeners for 'ready' and a few others to both scene and renderer.domElement, but no luck.   thanks.

Comment: well, i thought there was an event when adding an object to the scene. If not, maybe see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144840/eventdispatcher-r58

Concerning the toDataURL. I thought toDataURL relies on the Framebuffer so it does not care about the scene state. It would either show the screen with the object added or the frame before with the object missing. If you only get a black image, maybe your call for toDataURL is wrong? You need to add this directly after the render()-function and beforerenderer.clear() if you are not on "autoClear". If you are, maybe change it to false?

Comment: it may indeed be lower level (framebuffer or whatever); i am not sure.  i would believe that.  i know my call is not wrong because if i just wait and make the same call manually (from js console), it works fine.  it is just getting an all-transparent png when it grabs the data before three.js (or whatever lower) is finished.  i will try to see if i can find an event firing on _something_ when it is ready to be grabbed.